# what should be the placeholder name and image until user has completed his profile?

Tags: mobile, users, guidelines, experience, profile

I have an app where we show the name and profile picture on the menu page. The menu page can be seen without completing the profile also. At this point what would the most appropriate placeholder name and profile image?

Comment: Is there any value to the user to be able to visit the profile page without first completing their profile? Could you replace the name/profile image with some kind of "Complete your profile" call to action, which then takes the user to the profile edit view?

Comment: Yes profile completion is a long task here, don't want to intimidate user with long forms at start. And menu will be accessible to him during this time. And we show name and picture above menu.

Comment: I would cross reference this question: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/126062/are-there-any-suggested-username-conventions/126079#126079, and add that the suggested username should follow whatever your username conventions are. What if I don't choose a custom username? What have you already determined as my username?

Answer (score 0):

Names are chosen at account creation, so it should never be blank.

Most services use some generic image for the profile picture. This site appears to create random snowflake patterns, which prevents multiple users from having the same profile picture.

Comment: Our app will allow users to log in with mobile number otp verification only, they can do stuff inside and later they can complete profile. Meanwhile we have kept profile information on Central page which will be accessible by users without completing profile too. Thus i was thinking of random usernames to show there, until they complete profile.

Answer (score 0):

I think you hinted towards a very good solution in [your comment](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/126507/what-should-be-the-placeholder-name-and-image-until-user-has-completed-his-profi?noredirect=1#comment203165_126515):

> Thus i was thinking of random usernames to show there, until they complete profile.

**Auto-generating the username and image empowers users to "dive right in" without a fully completed profile.**

By auto-generating a username and using a default profile image (either unique or using a generic default), you not only solve your issue of how to represent this profile link when the profile is incomplete, but also allow your users—should this make sense in your use case—to fully interact with the site while still having their actions associated with their profile.

**The customization of these profile properties, then, is understood to be simply a display change, rather than a functional impediment.**

As long as customization of these auto-populated profile properties is easily discoverable, I don't see many downsides to this approach.